# Problem of overview with my created closed caption in Premiere CC

Tags: premiere

When I create a new closed caption on my video, nothing appears on my images. (I can see the overview on the closed caption monitor but nothing appears on my video)

Answer (score 1):

Closed captions are not sub-titles.  They are supposed to be encoded to be able to be turned on as an option by the final viewer.  If you want sub-titles you will need to do things a little bit differently.  Historically I've just used titles for further control over positioning and formatting.